# Entity object inside Async and Await process

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use Async and Await for upload process. I created a small code to see if it works.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TestAsync().Wait();
        }                
    }

    public static async Task TestAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var context = new CommonEntities();
            context.AddToDummies(new Dummy { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Caption = "Async" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it never gets to `Console.WriteLine`. If I replaced `var context = new EntityObject();` with `var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();` then it worked.

The idea is that I will create a method which has many complex procedures of saving and updating database as well as calling a webservice and store the result to database etc. Let say that method is called `MethodA`.

```
public static async void test()
{
    await Task.Run(() => MethodA());
}
```

But before going further, I am stuck in this simple test. Any idea why that is?

Comment: What's `EntityObject`?

Comment: How are you calling `test`? Is this a console application?

Comment: You have proven that the code in `new EntityObject` causes the problem. So show us that code.

Comment: Your problem is likely that you're using `async void` and the program is exiting before it has a chance to print (or throw an exception, if it's doing that). Use `async Task` and `await` or `.Wait()` the result.

Comment: @i3arnon EntityObject is ObjectContext class.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Yes, this is a console application for testing only.

Comment: @usr the actual code is var objectContext = new CommonEntities();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `async void` anywhere other than an event handler.

`async void` doesn't allow the caller to wait (asynchronously or otherwise) for the operation to complete, it just moves on. In your case it reaches the end of `Main` and the application ends before you get a chance to reach the `Console.WriteLine`.

You need to change `TestAsync` to return a `Task` and wait for it in `Main`:

```
static void Main()
{           
    TestAsync().Wait();
}

public static async Task TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var objectContext = new CommonEntities();
        Console.WriteLine("Processed");
    });
}
```

Comment: yes this works, but it seems that it has to wait until TestAsync() is finished before continue to the next step. lets say I modifed the code as above. Inside the loop, it has to wait TestAsync() to finish before it continues to the next one. That defeats the purpose of async, doesn't it? I am confused now.

Comment: The async method will return a Task object. Let's say you want to call 10 different functions to run in parallel. Store these 10 Task objects into a list. When you're done and want to wait until it's all done, call Tasks.WaitAll(TasksList)